# How do I find the area between two x values in a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

A normal distribution satisfies the following:

$$f(x)={\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {x-\mu }{\sigma }}\right)^{2}}$$

A z score is:

$z = \frac{x - \mu} {\sigma}$

Given standard deviation $\sigma$ and mean $\mu$ how do I calculate the possibility of a value falling into the range between two x values programmatically ***WITHOUT USING A Z-TABLE***.

More specifically, I want to calculate the area of the following five ranges:

$[\mu - 2.5\sigma, \mu - 1.5\sigma), [\mu - 1.5\sigma, \mu - 0.5\sigma), [\mu - 0.5\sigma, \mu + 0.5\sigma), [\mu + 0.5\sigma, \mu + 1.5\sigma), [\mu + 1.5\sigma, \mu + 2.5\sigma)$

[image]

If the starting x value is $x_0$, ending x values is $x_1$, let $x_\delta = x_1 - x_0$.

Obviously, the area $S$ of the shape bounded by the vertical lines $x_0$ and $x_1$ and the axis and the curve on the function curve is:

$$S = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(x_0 + \frac{i \cdot x_\delta} {n}) \cdot \frac{x_\delta}{n}$$

But it is not very efficient, what is a more mathematically elegant way to do this, maybe this is trivial, but my math is rusty and nothing I can find online gives a clue.

---

Wait! Don't close this question, I use Python, and nothing I found online addresses this issue, I want to know the mathematical equation to calculate the probability of a value falling into a range between two values in a normal distribution.

---

OK, I have already written the functions using the algorithms described above:

```
import math
def normpdf(x, mu, sd):                             
    denom = sd*(2*math.pi)**.5
    num = math.exp(-((x-mu)/sd)**2/2)
    return num/denom

def normpdrf(x1, x2, mu, sd):                             
    if x1 > x2:
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
    dx = (x2 - x1) / 1000
    return sum(normpdf(x1 + dx * i, mu, sd) * dx for i in range(1000))
```

And it gives me these:

```
In [154]: normpdrf(-0.5, 0.5, 0, 1)
Out[154]: 0.3829248932092479

In [155]: normpdrf(0.5, 1.5, 0, 1)
Out[155]: 0.2418416098023676

In [156]: normpdrf(1.5, 2.5, 0, 1)
Out[156]: 0.060653543128638646
```

But I think my algorithm is not good enough, so I want to know what is a better algorithm to calculate this?

Comment: This function is implemented in basically any programming language. For instance in R, give a look at `?pnorm`. Excel also lets you calculate the probabilities under those ranges. At my knowledge it doesn't exist a closed form way to calculate those. Take a look also at the wiki page of the error function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: In the wiki article I posted in the comment above there are tons of ways to numerically calculate what you are looking for.

Comment: Why is this question closed eight days after it was last modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CDF of the normal distribution is
$$
F(x) = \frac{1}{2}\text{erf}\Big(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\Big) + \frac{1}{2},
$$
where $\text{erf}(\cdot)$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). If you specify the interval as $[\mu - \alpha \sigma, \mu + \alpha \sigma)$, where $\alpha > 0$, then
$$
\text{Area} = F(\mu + \alpha\sigma) - F(\mu - \alpha\sigma).
$$
A Python implementation of this is

```
from math import erf, sqrt

def area(alpha, mu=1, sigma=1):
    def F(x):
        return 0.5*erf((x-mu)/(sigma*sqrt(2))) + 0.5

    a, b = mu - alpha*sigma, mu + alpha*sigma

    return F(b) - F(a)
```